# How to put custom toolbar inside fragment?

Tags: java, android

I created custom toolbar inside fragment,but i got view like this:
[image: ToolBar]

In themes.xml i disabled ActionBar:

```
<style name="Theme.Project" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

This is my custom toolbar layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Home"
                android:fontFamily="@font/google_sans"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is HomeFragment.java:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_in_home, container, false);

        return root;
    }
}
```

How to remove this white thing on top of screen?

UPD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is fragment home(just ConstraintLayout)

UPD2:i also was trying use toolbar in activity_main and it works:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_examination, R.id.navigation_profile)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }
```

[image: Screen Main]

But i can't do changes if i want to go on other fragment.
I need to set another custom toolbar layout with button like this:

[image]

Comment: add your fragment home xml code

Comment: Have you tried removing the action bar programmatically?

Comment: use your custom toolbar inside the main layout replace it from androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Comment: remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: @KristyWelsh i was trying getSupportActionBar().hide(); in MainActivity

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I did it. My app is based on single activity-multi-fragment model.

I had set activity theme to `AppTheme.NoActionBar`, so it enabled me to set a custom toolbar.

Later for each fragment I had a separate layout and within which added a custom toolbar like below

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
....
....
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Within this layout I had added menu items.

If you don't want to follow this, may be you should look at `getActionBar().setCustomView()`. Keep your activity theme set, so `getActionBar()` is not null.

You can control action bar layout by calling `getActionBar().setCustomView()` in fragment onResume() or probably when you are adding or removing a fragment in your activity.

Comment: Thanks that works.I enabled back ActionBar in themes.xml and used getActionBar().setCustomView() in HomeFragment

Answer (score 0):

You can use your **custom toolbar** inside the main layout replace it from `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`.

Here is an **example** code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navi"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/navi" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/header2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
 <include layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
</RelativeLayout>
```